# ng-include not work in PhoneGap

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to build my angularjs app into an android app using PhoneGap Build, but got stucked with the issue of the src of ng-include.

The code below tries to render a html of subheader into the view. It works perfectly in chrome browser, however after I convert the code with phonegap, it does not work. I also tried other path like '../templates/subheader.html' and '/templates/subheader.html', none of them work.

```
<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-stable" ng-include="'templates/subheader.html'">
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is embarrassing to always answer my own question...
However I finally figured it out.
1. The path inside the ng-include should not have the "/" on its left most.
2. The key of this issue is not the ng-include. It is because I was trying to fetch a variable stored in the $cookieStore:
For some reason I don't know, the data stored in $cookieStore can't persist between page transition. It impact many components in my page. So I have to change the $cookieStore to another local storage service https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, that my include was not shown on the device.
But my problem was that I put the template in an folder which's name started with an underscore `_`.
This is ignored in the build-process. Renaming the folder helped!

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a chance to look at [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) ? It works on phonegap and has build in AngularJS support. It also has some mobile ready components.